# How to show TextView value in ImageView?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview, textview

I would like to allow my users to type a word into a `TextView` and then display a corresponding picture in an `ImageView`. For example, the user might type "Moon", and then I would display `moon.png`.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: are you loading moon.png from drawable or local storage?

Comment: yes.. I'm friend...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Find TextView and ImageView, if required
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);

// Get text from TextView
String myText = textView.getText().toString();

// Get ID of drawable with name entered by user
Context context = myImageView.getContext();
int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(myText, "drawable", context.getPackageName());

// Set that drawable as the image to be displayed in the ImageView
myImageView.setImageResource(id);
```

Comment: Can you put this part of your code here?
As well as the part where you initialize the imageView.
Also, are you storing the image in your Drawables directory?

Comment: It's okay now bro.. u helpme alot .. It was not inside the onCreate... now are and works perfectly.. =D ... THX!!

Comment: Can u help me with other thing?

Answer (score 1):

The `Resources` class has a method `getIdentifier()` that you can use here.

> `int getIdentifier(String name, String defType, String defPackage)`
>
> Return a resource identifier for the given resource name. A fully qualified resource name is of the form "package:type/entry". The first two components (package and type) are optional if defType and defPackage, respectively, are specified here.
>
> Note: use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.

That means you could write:

```
String userEntered = myEditText.getText().toString();
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(userEntered, "drawable", getPackageName());
myImageView.setImageResource(id);
```

Comment: Hi Ben.. have an error in this line myImageView.setImageResource(id);